# Springboot Junit test NoClassDefFoundError EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test, spring-webflux

I created a springboot (2) webflux project as follow :

JPA Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable
{
...
}
```

Spring repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>
{
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UserService
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    ...
}
```

Webflux Handler

```
@Component
public class UserHandler
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getUser(ServerRequest request)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

RouteConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class RouteConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public static RouterFunction<ServerResponse> userRoutes(UserHandler userHandler)
    {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/user"), userHandler:: getUser);
    }
```

WebApp

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class);
    }
}
```

POM

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Everything run fine, I can start my server and use it. I would like now to code some tests. Here is what I did :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebApplication.class)
public class UserHandlerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;
    private WebTestClient testClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        testClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUser()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

What ever I tried, I got an error with hibernate dependencies during "mvn clean install" process :

> [ERROR] testUser(...UserHandlerTest)  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl

I know JPA works in blocking way but I want to avoid to use NoSQL DB for this project. Did I miss something ? Thank you a lot for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test my Spring Webflux controllers, I finally use the WebFluxTest annotation. It works as expected :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RouteConfiguration.class, UserHandler.class})
@WebFluxTest
public class UserHandlerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    @MockBean(name="userService")
    private UserService userService;
    private WebTestClient testClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        testClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).build();
    }

    ...
```

As I do not use RestController annotation but functional endpoints I had to use ContextConfiguration and manually instantiate the WebTestClient.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are missing details which we need to provide for datasource under src/main/resources. you can check https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-data-mongo/src/main/resources/application.yml. this might help you.

Comment: Dear Yogendra, I am using a datasource for runtime, but during test I would like to Mock the UserService thanks to MockBean annotation. This should be enough ? I tried anyway to create an application-test.profile with a h2 database and use ActiveProfiles on my test cases but the same error still occurs.